# How to return results values from sql Query to bot application as reply using c#

Tags: c#, sql, botframework

I have been trying to build conversation in c# using Bot application and testing in Bot Framework emulator, So I tried to enter my name bot will replay my id as from return results of the query, but it's not working
this is a code example:

```
if (activity.Text == "Ram")
                {
                    SqlConnection botc = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = SRINIVASG - PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Botdb; Integrated Security = True");
                    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select id from Bot_dt where Name = '"+ activity.Text + "'", botc);
                    SqlDataAdapter Ad = new SqlDataAdapter("Select id from Bot_dt where Name = '"+ activity.Text + "'", botc);
                    DataTable bt = new DataTable();
                    Ad.Fill(bt);                    
                    Activity replyaa = activity.CreateReply($"Mr.{activity.Text}, Your ID is {bt}");
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(replyaa);
                }
```

Comment: I know you the text have to be 'Ram' but imagine if 'activity.Text' was "';drop database Botdb;select'"

Comment: @tymtam I can't get you, can you please tell me bit briefly

Comment: Jai,@tymtam is speaking about SQL injections. Anyway- i have 2 points. 1. I dont see You have opened connection => botc.Open(), 2. You sure You have spaces in Data Source ?

Comment: @KubaDo There are two issues, now it's both fixed, your second point as solved my first issue, I didn't notice that, thanks for figuring out

Answer (score 0):

`DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)` runs your SQL query on the server and adds the result to the `DataTable`.

The `DataTable` has Rows and the Rows has columns, which you can get with `DataTable.Rows[rowno]["columnname"]`.

In your example the id is retrieved with `var bot_id = bt.Rows[0]["id"]`. That will give you the first (if there are many, and a Exception if there are none) robot id with that name.

Comment: But since you are only interested in a single value, I would recommend you to have a look at `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`. That will return the first matching value without the overhead of creating and filling a `DataTable`.

Comment: You really have to give some more information. Man.

Comment: it's fixed now, it's connecting string issue, anyhow thanks for replying